# How to use .then function properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to load two fonts from disk using the JIMP library for node.js. Then printing text on an image using the loaded fonts. However the fonts are not loading in time as the function is async and continuing to write the text on the image leading to nothing being written. The code within the .then() is executing before the font is correctly loaded

```
function generateStatsImage(statsJsonObject){
var stats = statsJsonObject;
var mainImage = Jimp.read("./template/StatsTemplate.png")
.then(function(image){
  loadedBackground = image;
  var ubuntu36whitefont = Jimp.loadFont("./ubuntu36white.fnt");
  var ubuntu28whitefont = Jimp.loadFont("./ubuntu28white.fnt");
  return (ubuntu36whitefont, ubuntu28whitefont);
})
.then(function(ubuntu36whitefont, ubuntu28whitefont){
  image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 130, 152 , stats.stats.p2.top1.value);
  image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 337, 152 , stats.stats.p10.top1.value);
  image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 542, 152 , stats.stats.p9.top1.value);
  image.write("stats.png"); // save
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log("catch error: " + err);
});
};
```

Comment: I assume `loadFont` is async,.. so you will need to handle like the other promises,..  `return (ubuntu36whitefont, ubuntu28whitefont);` what Javascript concept is this?.

Comment: Didnt know you could return more than two things which is easy fix. But how do you handle promises correctly

Comment: A promise can only return one value,. that's why I pointed out that syntax,  eg.  `return (x,y)` makes no sense in JS, it will just return y..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` is possibly your friend here, if you have multiple promises you want to wait on.  It will then return an array with the resolved promises.

eg.

```
function generateStatsImage(statsJsonObject){
var stats = statsJsonObject;
var mainImage = Jimp.read("./template/StatsTemplate.png")
.then(function(image){
  loadedBackground = image;
  var ubuntu36whitefont = Jimp.loadFont("./ubuntu36white.fnt");
  var ubuntu28whitefont = Jimp.loadFont("./ubuntu28white.fnt");
  //lets use promise.all so we can wait for all fonts
  return Promise.all([ubuntu36whitefont, ubuntu28whitefont]);
})
.then(function(ret){
  //ret has our array of resolved promises, lets put into vars
  var ubuntu36whitefont = ret[0];
  var ubuntu28whitefont = ret[1];
  image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 130, 152 , stats.stats.p2.top1.value);
  image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 337, 152 , stats.stats.p10.top1.value);
  image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 542, 152 , stats.stats.p9.top1.value);
  image.write("stats.png"); // save
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log("catch error: " + err);
});
};
```

ps.  if you can use modern JS, a lot of the above can look a lot nicer.. `async / await`..  Array destructuring for the promises,.. etc.

eg.

```
async function generateStatsImage(statsJsonObject){
  try {
    const stats = statsJsonObject;
    //lets use promise.all so we can wait for all fonts & image
    const [image, ubuntu36whitefont, ubuntu28whitefont] = 
      await Promise.all([
        Jimp.read("./template/StatsTemplate.png"),
        Jimp.loadFont("./ubuntu36white.fnt"), 
        Jimp.loadFont("./ubuntu28white.fnt") 
      ]);
    image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 130, 152 , stats.stats.p2.top1.value);
    image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 337, 152 , stats.stats.p10.top1.value);
    image.print(ubuntu28whitefont, 542, 152 , stats.stats.p9.top1.value);
    image.write("stats.png"); // save
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("catch error: " + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like there is support for async and await. I will have a look on how I can implement those.

Comment: @SnamakoolLP  Done an update showing the `async / await` pattern, not only is it much shorter code, but way easier to follow and understand.